# How to fire a new css animation when the element already has one?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I have this element which already has an animation that fires at some time:

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 87.5%;
  background: #DDD;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12.5%;
  left: 0%;
  -webkit-animation: load 0.5s ease-out 5s backwards;
  animation: load 0.5s ease-out 5s backwards;
}
```

But at some time, always after that animation has finished I want to fire a new animation on the same element. So I thought that creating a new class and attaching it to the element with JS would work:

```
.unload{
  -webkit-animation: unload 0.5s ease-out 0.5s backwards !important;
  animation: unload 0.5s ease-out 0.5s backwards !important;
}

document.querySelector(".box").classList.add('unload');
```

But it doesn't work. The class gets added but the animation doesn't happen.
Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Since all animation properties are the same except the name, try setting `animation-name` instead of the whole animation property

Comment: I'm sorry to introduce jQuery, but you can try `$.animate({},timeDelay, callbackFunction)`. And inside callback func, you can again animate.

Comment: Another alternative could be adding a setTimeout on load of this element and then add another class of second animation. But not sure if this works work. Also i would suggest use of animate function.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your code? Please, add jsFiddle... Your code is doing no animation at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyframe's names were slightly different and didn't fit the call. Sorry, it was quite stupid...

Answer (score 0):

Six years down the line and I had the same problem, which somehow I was able to figure out. I might as well just share it.

What helped me was specificity. Instead of applying the modifier class directly to the animated element I applied it to the parent div and used the descendant selector like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container container--unload"> //this second class can be added later with JS
  <div class="box">
    //some feature here
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 87.5%;
  background: #DDD;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12.5%;
  left: 0%;
  animation: load 0.5s ease-out 5s backwards;
}

.container--unload .box{
  animation: unload 0.5s ease-out 0.5s backwards;
}
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelector(".container").classList.add("container--unload");
```

Tested and seems to be working. I left out the keyframes.

Cheers!